# I have some issue putting variable into the path

Tags: python, linux, variables

it 's possible to put a variable into the path in python/linux

for example :

```
>>>counter = 0;

>>>image = ClImage(file_obj=open('/home/user/image'counter'.jpeg', 'rb'))
```

I have syntax error when i do that.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) might be helpful here

Comment: @Castelo If an answer here has helped you, standard practice on SO is to accept it. Please accept which ever answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) if you’re working in python 3.6+

This is the most efficient method.

```
counter = 0
filepath = f"/home/user/image{counter}.jpeg"
image = ClImage(file_obj=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```

Otherwise the second best would be using the [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
counter = 0
filepath = "/home/user/image{0}.jpeg".format(counter)
image = ClImage(file_obj=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [.format()](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) method:

```
counter = 0
filepath = '/home/user/image{0}.jpeg'.format(counter)
image = ClImage(file_obj=open(filepath, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [string concatenation](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

```
>>>counter = 0;

>>>image = ClImage(file_obj=open('/home/user/image' + str(counter) + '.jpeg', 'rb'))
```